# Can upgrading my system from Ubuntu 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS delete my other partiion's data?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade, 22.04

I want to upgrade Ubuntu from 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS. My Ubuntu is installed on a different partition. If something goes wrong, is it possible that I lose my other partition data?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: An upgrade will not make changes to your partitions. At no point will you need to format or risk losing data 

Answer (score 2):

Anything you upgrade your computer - and even on daily use of your computer - something may go wrong. That is why it is mandatory to maintain a good backup of your own user data. Your personal user data, once lost, is lost forever. Your operating system, once lost, is readily downloaded and reinstalled, usually even in a better version than it was before.

With that out of the way, concerns about losing data on other partitions also are out of the way.

In general, upgrading Ubuntu will not affect any other partitions on your system, even also not on the drive where Ubuntu is being installed. However, ultimately, it depends on you: how you do the upgrade and what choices you make in the installer.

As for the specific answer to your question, **upgrading** your operating system can be done in different ways: through a **reinstallation** or through **upgrading the existing system**.

When you **upgrading the existing system** through the internet, i.e., after being prompted by the upgrade tool or with the `do-release-upgrade` command will not erase the partition, the current system partition is not erased, nor reformatted. Existing system files are overwritten, existing system configuration is conserved or overwritten (the installer prompts).

One can also upgrade an operating  system through **reinstallation** using  USB or DVD installation media. The default option is to erase and repartition the entire drive. So there, any existing partitions on the selected drive will be erased. The other option is "Something else", where you indicate yourself where the system must be installed. Then it is a matter not to be confused or make mistakes.

Still, something may go wrong during an upgrade, either by human mistake or an issue with software or hardware. Make sure your backup is up to date before you start.